# Understanding ExpressJS application start-up

Tags: node.js, express

I am struggling with how application start-up works in Express. I am going to explain my use-case:

I have a configuration-Manager module which is used by all other application modules to load required configuration. I am setting configuration in `app.listen`:

```
app.listen(9000, function () {
    try
    {
        config_manager.setSiteConfig();
        console.log('settings..!!!')
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
});
```

In another module of the same application I call the Configuration-Manager function to load config, but it returns empty. Code is something like this:

```
var config_manager = require('configuration-manager');
console.log(config_manager.loadConfig()); // returns empty object {}
```

I am running the application using `node app.js`. The empty object gets printed first then `('settings..!!!')`. Does Express compile the script before calling `app.listen()`? How do I make sure that my configuration is set before compilation/loading other files?

Answer (score 0):

Express indeed first processes all statements in a file, basically anything that isn't in a function on startup. 
In your case `var config_manager = require('configuration-manager');
console.log(config_manager.loadConfig()); // returns empty object {}` is executed before your `app.listen` because you are requering the config before the `app.listen`.

You're best off processing your configuration right after the first time it is required (if `app.js` is your main file, this means the first time it comes across a `require` statement pointing to `configuration-manager` in any file).

This should make your code work:

```
var config_manager = require('configuration-manager');
try {
    config_manager.setSiteConfig();
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
}
console.log(config_manager.loadConfig()); // returns empty object {}
```

and then

```
app.listen(9000, function () {
    console.log('settings..!!!', config_manager.loadConfig()) // Should correctly print your config
 });
```

If this doesn't work the problem does not lay in the order of execution.

Comment: Configuration are loaded in seperate file (other then app.js). I am setting config file to be loaded in app.listen